# SIFT SURF on raspberry

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

Does anyone know if the raspberry pi 3 is powerful enough to run the SIFT or SURF algorithms for a real-time app (traffic signs recognition) or should I look for something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried `ORB` on Raspberry Pi and got like around 5 FPS at 640 x 480 I think, it was on single thread, could probably get up to like at least 15-20 fps with threads. You're better off using `ORB` with something like Raspberry Pi. I doubt you can get good FPS using `SIFT/SURF`.